# SwifUI contextMenu Cell preview

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm making an app in swiftUI and I wanted to see if anyone knows how to do the following effect with contextMenu:
[image]
What I want is that when the contextMenu function is called

```
CellView().contextMenu { }
```

show me another View or the preview, as seen in the twitter example.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `func contextMenu<M, P>(menuItems: () -> M, preview: () -> P) -> some View`

```
.contextMenu(menuItems: {
    Text("your menu items")
}, preview: {
    Text("preview")
})
```